# How to use same MPLS Traffic Engineering tunnel for ipv4 and ipv6

Tags: cisco, ipv6, tunneling, mpls

I have MPLS TE configured and working, but it is currently using IPV4 and I needed to include IPV6.
My current tunnel configuration is the following:

```
interface Tunnel1
 ip unnumbered Loopback0
 ipv6 enable
 tunnel destination 200.0.0.2
 tunnel mode mpls traffic-eng
 tunnel mpls traffic-eng autoroute announce
 tunnel mpls traffic-eng priority 7 7
 tunnel mpls traffic-eng bandwidth  2000
 tunnel mpls traffic-eng path-option 1 dynamic
 no routing dynamic
!
```

I know I need to activate `ipv6 cef`.
I have currently configured PBR (Policy Based Routing) to route all the traffic I need through this tunnel:

```
access-list 101 permit icmp 81.100.1.192 0.0.0.63 81.100.1.0 0.0.0.63

route-map trafficTOOPorto permit 10
 match ip address 101
 set interface Tunnel1
!
```

I wanted to know how can I achieve the same but using IPV6 (which I have configured in all other interfaces of the network). I already know that IPV6 is not supported by MPLS. So what should I do?

Comment: What model router and what version of IOS?

Comment: I am doing this in GNS3. The Router model is `Router c3700` and IOS version is `Version 12.4(21)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup required for forwarding IPv6 traffic over an MPLS network is called 6PE. Rather than using RSVP or LDP to distribute labels, BGP Labeled Unicast (BGP-LU) is used. They key to enabling 6PE is the activation of the BGP-LU Network Layer Reachability Information (NLRI).

Here are configuration examples for Junos and IOS.

```
Junos
[edit protocols bgp]
group 6PE {
    [...]
    family inet6 {
        labeled-unicast {
            explicit-null;
        }
    }
    [...]
}

IOS
address-family ipv6
  neighbor x.x.x.x activate
  neighbor x.x.x.x send-label
  network 2001:DB8:FFFF::/48
  exit-address-family
```

There are some tricky issues involved such as setting of the BGP next hop. All of these are documented on the web. You can find numerous example configurations as well. Use the text "6PE" and your vendor's name.